# Define storage caps per app basis

Tags: applications, settings, storage

Is there any way to define how much storage space an app can use?

I'm tired of uninstalling apps, deleting apps data and deleting files to see the newly freed space begin swallowed in just  some hours by those "storage abusive" apps!

The worst of all is that I have real needs with some of those apps.
Take Outlook for example, it wastes space caching old e-mails that I'll not read and it lacks any settings to control this behavior. I use it with my personal and work accounts and cleaning its data means going through the authentication steps again... for each of the accounts... on a daily basis... and it's just one of those problematic apps...

Using the "delete things" method repeatedly\constantly looks just dumb, a poor made process design choice...

And i don't care about loss of functionality, they'll have to deal with whatever space i judge them worthy having. =)

Comment: With root access it's possible to set filesystem quotas. But that too won't be helpful for external storage (`/sdcard`) where all files are saved with same UID/GID irrespective of which app creates them. So apps with WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission cannot be subjected to filesystem quotas. Or at max you may set a limit on total size of `/sdcard`. For other apps the approach will work perfectly. However quotas are not implemented by Android this way. You'll have to manage them manually. And possibly apps may break when they reach quota limit since they are not aware if it.

Comment: The IMHO better way to stop "storage abusive"  is write a review and/or contact the developer and complain about this behavior. Or just use a different mail app. BTW: Do you know that Outlook app does not access your mail servers directly? AFAIK instead they send your username and password to a Microsoft server named "Outlook cloud service" (where it is stored) which now manages everything and to this server the app connects. Therefore every mail you receive/send/read goes through this server. Very creepy and a total privacy disaster.