# Reduce space taken by Outlook

Tags: internal-storage, outlook

Outlook is eating up space in my Samsung J7 prime. I am currently working with something between 100Mb and zero free space.
If I free up some space, it seems Outlook increases its occupied space.

**Is there any way to tell Outlook which folders I want it to sync?**

**Or any other way to limit (e.g., from the OS) the space it takes?**

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/220355/define-storage-caps-per-app-basis#comment284651_220355

Comment: @IrfanLatif - Related... and with no answers.

Comment: No answers because it's not possible. See my comment.

Answer (score 1):

I know this may not be an exact answer, but I ultimately switched to Android Firefox web browser (or your favorite browser), with desktop homepage link to outlook.offfice.com and... it behaves perfectly. That is, assuming your email account is served there...

MS actually did pretty good job with their mobile web page rendering and functionality, and so far I do not miss any functionality (email, calendar...) from my bloated Outlook for Android app (800MB unmovable local storage!).

Hope this helps somebody.

Comment: I guess the only problem with this is you don't get alerts for new "focused" emails.

Comment: That is not an option for me...